# Escaping space in directory name while doing git sparse checkout

Tags: git, jenkins

Trying to use the `git sparse` checkout in jenkins. But this thing doesn't seem to like the ways which i am trying use to get a sub-directory with space in the name.

E.g. i am trying to get the folder:

`/foo/bar baz/folder/desired_folder`

[image]

I have already tried like so with no luck:

`"/foo/bar baz/folder/desired_folder"`
`/foo/bar\ baz/folder/desired_folder`

The same nature is seen while using the git bash to verify the sparse checkout. 
Is there a way to escape the space. Else i have to rename the folders and checkin again

Comment: `%20` worth to try as well. But I'm quite sure that GUI is not a friend of a developer.

Comment: Its not just on the GUI. The git-sparse option in git itself, doesn't respect the conventional escaping of spaces in the `.git/info/sparse-checkout`

Comment: I see, only what I can suggest is not to use space in pathnames, less headache.

Comment: Which version of Jenkins and which version of the Git plugin are you using?

Comment: Jenkins ver. 1.625.18.5 (CloudBees Jenkins Operations Center 1.8), Git plugin 3.0.0.. Is from one of the 2 setup's that have failed. My local open sourced jenkins instance fails as well. Also the git client version, with which i tried the git-sparse manually by removing jenkins from the equation. git version 2.11.0.windows.3

Answer (score 4):

I just encountered this issue and here's what worked for me, in `git version 2.10.2.windows.1`.

Test repo that I created for this example: https://github.com/dixon/TestSparseCheckout

Following [these excellent instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13738951/3), here's the `echo` command I used - **I didn't escape anything**, but I added an `*`:

```
$ echo "Folder With Spaces/*" >> .git/info/sparse-checkout

$ cat .git/info/sparse-checkout
Folder With Spaces/*
```

And then verification:

```
$ git pull origin master
From https://github.com/dixon/TestSparseCheckout
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD

$ ls
total 8.0K
drwxr-xr-x 1 dixon 0 Mar 21 14:21 ./
drwxr-xr-x 1 dixon 0 Mar 21 14:19 ../
drwxr-xr-x 1 dixon 0 Mar 21 14:21 .git/
drwxr-xr-x 1 dixon 0 Mar 21 14:21 'Folder With Spaces'/

$ ls Folder\ With\ Spaces/
total 1.0K
drwxr-xr-x 1 dixon  0 Mar 21 14:21 ./
drwxr-xr-x 1 dixon  0 Mar 21 14:21 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 dixon 10 Mar 21 14:21 'Should Checkout.txt'
```

Looks like it worked; the [`DoNotCheckout`](https://github.com/dixon/TestSparseCheckout/tree/master/DoNotCheckout) wasn't downloaded.