# Git Sparse checkout ignore a bad directory

Tags: git, git-sparse-checkout

I have a directory name "[afdsklj]" in my git repo. It seems that git sparse checkout still gives me fatal error invalid argument when it tries to create the new directory. Is there someway to have git exclude this bad directory altogether?

Answer (score 0):

Check first if you can escape those characters in your git sparse-checkout definition:

```
 \[afdsklj\]
```

If not, [as in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42935435/6309), try and add wildcards:

```
 *afdsklj*
```

Comment: the folder in question is inside another folder. However, excluding the parent folder doesn't prevent it from causing this error. I suspect that it may be because Git tries to create the folder first and then filter the files based on the sparse-checkout patterns